# Multiple where clause using checkboxes in C#

Tags: c#, sql, where-clause

I am trying to use a multiple where clause in C# using checkboxes. After selecting the appropriate checkboxes, I have a button and on its click the code fires. The objective is to filter out results. The code I am using is giving a blank output. Help Needed!!

The C# code is as follows:

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<String> wheres = new List<String>();

    if (CheckBox1.Checked)
    {
        wheres.Add("pepsi");
    }

    if (CheckBox2.Checked)
    {
        wheres.Add("coke");
    }

    if (CheckBox3.Checked)
    {
        wheres.Add("juice");
    }
    String whereclause = String.Join(" AND item_name=", wheres.ToArray());
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=XXXXXX; Initial Catalog=XXXXX; Integrated Security=True";
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select item_ID from items where item_name='" + whereclause + "'", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: single quote for the values: item_name='pepsi'..... Also check should it be AND or OR?

Comment: yeah single quote issue i think... let me check

Answer (score 3):

Your query should probably look something like this :

```
select item_ID from items where item_name in ('pepsi','coke');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding '.

```
String whereclause = String.Join("' AND item_name='", wheres.ToArray());
String whereclause += "'";
```

Single quote is mandatory working with strings (char, varchar). The result must be:

```
WHERE item_name='pepsi'
```

Not

```
WHERE item_name=pepsi
```

Comment: Also: to avoid [sql injection](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), I suggest to you the use of parameters:

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_name", "pepsi");`

Comment: Well I tried to tweek the code as you said and also I forgot to mention in my question that if I check a single checkbox, I get the record but if I check more than 1, its blank!!

Comment: Do you want that all your wheres are true all together or true of only one is true?
In the first case "AND" is correct. In the second one, replace it with an "OR", or use IN ('pepsi', 'coke', 'juice').

Answer (score 1):

Check the `string.join` and the SQL query:

```
String whereclause = String.Join(",", wheres.Select(w => "'"+w+"'").ToArray());
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=XXXXXX; Initial Catalog=XXXXX; Integrated Security=True";
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select item_ID from items where item_name in (" + whereclause + ")", conn);
```

You have to first build a list: 'item1', 'item2'...

Then inject it in the `where` clause using `in`.